# RingCentral Subscription Webhook With Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, webhooks, ringcentral

I'm trying to have RingCentral send information directly to my Google Sheet setting a subscription.

Using the function the RingCentral require to answer the initial request adding the validation token to the `Validation-Token` header which RingCentral sends in the same header. I can't find a way to access the header from the request I receive with `doPost(e)`, and I don't know how to answer this request with the proper validation code so I basically cant close the loop and start using the registration.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Google Apps Scripts cannot access headers in `doPost(e)`, even for Google's own `x-goog` prefix headers. You can follow the issue and feature request here:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/67764685

As a workaround, I wrote a service called "[RingCentral Permahooks](https://github.com/grokify/ringcentral-permahooks)" that can be used as a go between between RingCentral and Google Apps Scripts by handling the validation token in the Permahooks service and also not-requiring it for the downstream service, Google Sheets Apps Scripts in this case.

https://github.com/grokify/ringcentral-permahooks